# удалить наибольший из пересекающиеся элементов в списке кортежей

Tags: python, list, множества, кортежи

для решения задачи мне необходимо решить подзадачу:

Вариант А:

Дан список кортежей: `both = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (6, 7), (7, 8)]`
необходимо оставить меньший из кортежей, содержащих одинаковую цифру
т.е. в случае с примером необходимо получить: [(1, 2), (4, 5), (6, 7)]

Пробовал:

```
ans = []
for i in range(len(both)-1):
    if set(both[i]) & set(both[i+1]):
        ans.append(max(both[i], both[i+1]))
ans1 = []
for i in both:
    if i not in ans:
        ans1.append(i)
print(ans1)
```

т.е. сначало получил больший из двух пересекающихся кортежей, потом не взял его в новый список...
но что то мне подсказывает что это некрасивое решение, вот и хотел бы спросить, как решить более изящно и по питоновски...

Вариант Б:

дано два списка кортежей:

a = [(4, 5), (7, 8)] и b = [(1, 2), (6, 7)]

необходимо собрать их в один список, в котором из двух содержащих одинаковые значения кортежей место займет меньший...

Comment: кортежи всегда отсортированы ? т.е. там НЕ может быть такого кортежа `(4, 3)`

Comment: да, кортежи всегда отсортированы, нулевое значение в кортеже всегда будет меньше первого значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант №1:

```
both = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (6, 7), (7, 8)]

d = dict(both)
for k in dict(d):
    if k in d.values():
        d.pop(k)
        continue

result = list(d.items())
print(result)
```

Вариант №2:

```
both = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (6, 7), (7, 8)]

result = []
for el in both:
    if el[0] not in (n[1] for n in result):
        result.append(el)
print(result)
```

Вариант №3:

```
both = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (6, 7), (7, 8)]

d = dict()
for el in both:
    if el[0] not in d.values():
        d[el[0]] = el[1]
        
result = list(d.items())
print(result)
```

---

Тесты производительности:

```
import time

def elapsed(f):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    r = f()
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    return (finish-start, r)

def f1(both):
    d = dict(both)
    for k in dict(d):
        if k in d.values():
            d.pop(k)
            continue
    return list(d.items())

def f2(both):
    result = []
    for el in both:
        if el[0] not in (n[1] for n in result):
            result.append(el)
    return result

def f3(both):
    d = dict()
    for el in both:
        if el[0] not in d.values():
            d[el[0]] = el[1]
    return list(d.items())

def test(both):    
    t1, r1 = elapsed(lambda: f1(both))
    t2, r2 = elapsed(lambda: f2(both))
    t3, r3 = elapsed(lambda: f3(both))

    assert r1==r2
    assert r2==r3

    return t1, t2, t3

def main():
    s1 = s2 = s3 = 0
    both = []
    for i in range(10**3):
        t = test(both)
        s1 += t[0]
        s2 += t[1]
        s3 += t[2]
        both.append((i, i+1))
        if not i%1000:
            print(f'{s1:5.2f}', f'{s2:5.2f}', f'{s3:5.2f}')
    
main()
```

Вывод:

```
 0.00  0.00  0.00
 2.25  5.00  1.14
17.73 39.98  8.82
```

Как видно из тестов лучше всего использовать вариант №3.

Comment: Ого! На все бы мои вопросы получать такой подробнейший и развернутый ответ :) Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

можно еще такой вариант потестировать:

```
a,b = zip(*both)
ans = [both[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] not in b]
```